# How to insert SQL data into an autocomplete jquery list

Tags: jquery, sql, autocomplete, textbox

I was trying to modify the code in the snippet:

https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

to allow me to have the autocomplete list populated with the result of an SQL query instead of static.

It's gonna live on an asp.net c# page.

I'm not very fluent in jQuery so maybe it's an easy one, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

tnx
~j

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the data via the [source option](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source). Here's super simplified snippet:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  source: "https://mywebsite.com/getData.php"
});
```

Everytime the user types in the autocomplete, a request is sent with a querystring to send the search `term`, like if the user types 'java': `https://mywebsite.com/getData.php?term=java`